# Multi select drop-down items auto select attribute on update

Tags: c#, asp.net, multi-select

On a page i have a multi select drop-down menu. It works fine whenever i need to insert data BUT a problem accrues when i need to update the inserted data.

**The Problem** Whenever i click the edit button next to my data (in my case - about book data) every field inside the Form fills up but the select drop-down menu items does not get auto selected to what was previously selected. I have to re-select it manually again. The process of updating the data itself works fine (once i re-select it again).

It uses many-to-many relationship. Worked fine when i used check-boxes but I want to re-do it on drop-down menu.

**The Controller**

```
public ViewResult Index(int? Id)
        {
            SelectList selectList = new SelectList(_authorRepository.GetAllAuthors()
                    .Select(x => new { x.Id, Title = x.Name + " " + x.Lastname }), "Id", "Title");
            BooksIndexViewModel viewModel = new BooksIndexViewModel()
            {
                Books = _booksRepository.GetAllBooks(),
                AuthorOptions = selectList,
                authors = _authorRepository.GetAllAuthors(),
                Book = _booksRepository.GetBook(Id ?? 0),
                publishers = _publisherRepository.GetAllPublishers(),
                indexPage = _dataRepository.Generatedata("Knygos", Id,
                    ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())
            };
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

The `AuthorOptions` is what passes the asp-items.
The Form itself uses `Book`.

**Index.cshtml** (other lines where removed, only form left)

```
<form asp-controller="@Model.indexPage.controller" 
    asp-action="@Model.indexPage.action" 
    asp-route-id="@if (Model.indexPage.routeId.HasValue) {@Model.indexPage.routeId.Value}"  method="post">
        <div class="inputs">
            <div> <input asp-for="@Model.Book.Title" /> </div>
            <div> <select asp-for="@Model.Book.BookAuthors" 
                asp-items="@Model.AuthorOptions" name="author[]"></select> </div>
            <div>
                <select asp-for="@Model.Book.PublisherId"  
                    asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.publishers, "Id", "Title"))"></select>
            </div>
            <div><input asp-for="@Model.Book.Cost" /></div>
            <div><input asp-for="@Model.Book.Code" /></div>
            <div><input asp-for="@Model.Book.InvNr" /></div>
            <div><input asp-for="@Model.Book.Description" /></div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```

The line that im after is `<select asp-for="@Model.Book.BookAuthors" asp-items="@Model.AuthorOptions" name="author[]"></select>`. It, and the entire Form, gets data form my repository.

**The repository**

```
public Book GetBook(int Id)
        {
            return db.Books.Include(x => x.BookAuthors).SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
        }
```

The `Value` inside the drop-down is `AuthorId`, the `BookAuthors` inside the `Book` model is a `IList` and connected to a `BookAuthor` model:

```
public class BookAuthor
    {
        public int BookId { get; set; }
        public Book Book { get; set; }
        public int AuthorId { get; set; }
        public Author Author { get; set; }
    }
```

So the problem is, why whenever i get the Book's data (from my Id) all the fields (including `PublisherID` that is a drop-down but single-to-single connection) gets selected BUT my Authors drop-down does not? What am I missing?

**EDIT 1**

By changing `asp-for="@Model.Book.BookAuthors"` => `asp-for="@Model.Book.BookAuthors[0].AuthorId"` Does the Trick in order to get selected BUT if the book data has more then 1 author, only 1 author is selected from drop-down meniu. + the drop-down becomes no longer multi-select but can be overridden by adding attribute `multiple` but still only select 1 item from the drop-down menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out a trick.

In a viewModel created a IList of integer `public IList<int> AuthorIds`. inside the .cshtml, int the `asp-for=""` used the newly created integer list `AuthorIds`. Inside the controller, the `AuthorIds` in the ViewModel gets passed with `_booksRepository.GetBook(Id).BookAuthors.Select(x => x.AuthorId).ToList();`

So the project looks like this:

**Controller**

```
public ViewResult Index(int? Id)
        {
            BooksIndexViewModel viewModel = new BooksIndexViewModel()
            {
                Books = _booksRepository.GetAllBooks(),
                AuthorOptions = new SelectList(_authorRepository.GetAllAuthors()
                    .Select(x => new { x.Id, Title = x.Name + " " + x.Lastname }), "Id", "Title"),
                Book = _booksRepository.GetBook(Id),
                publishers = _publisherRepository.GetAllPublishers(),
                indexPage = _dataRepository.Generatedata("Knygos", Id,
                    ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())
            };
            if (Id != null)
                viewModel.AuthorIds = _booksRepository.GetBook(Id).BookAuthors.Select(x => x.AuthorId).ToList();
            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

**cshtml**

```
<form asp-controller="@Model.indexPage.controller" asp-action="@Model.indexPage.action"
          asp-route-id="@if (Model.indexPage.routeId.HasValue) {@Model.indexPage.routeId.Value}" 
          method="post" class="form grid">
        <div class="inputs">
            <div><input asp-for="@Model.Book.Title" class="w100" /></div>
            <div><select asp-for="@Model.AuthorIds" asp-items="@Model.AuthorOptions"
                name="author[]" multiple></select></div>
            <div><select asp-for="@Model.Book.PublisherId" 
                        asp-items="@(new SelectList(Model.publishers, "Id", "Title"))">
            </select></div>
            <div><input asp-for="@Model.Book.Cost" /></div>
            <div><input asp-for="@Model.Book.Code" /></div>
            <div><input asp-for="@Model.Book.InvNr" /></div>
            <div><input asp-for="@Model.Book.Description" /></div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Save</button>
    </form>
```

Nothing else has changed.